# Azure bicep Pass Storage Account Connection String to Secret Keyvault loop issue

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a the following bicep script to perform the following steps:

- Create storage accounts based on code
- create a key
- encrypt storage account with the correct key
- generate a secret connection string (storage account) into a key vault

The infra is splitted into 2 resource groups:

```
rg-shared => where the 2 key vault are (1 keyvault for key and GUID, and 1 keyvault for secrets (connection string)

rg-storage-account => where all the storage account get created
```

In azure bicep I have the following scripts:

**Storage.bicep**

```
param ManagedIdentityid string
param uri string 
param kvname string
param keyvaultrg string = 'XXXX' //<== SHARED Resource Group
var keyVaultKeyPrefix = 'Key-Data-'
var storagePrefix = 'sthritesteur'
param tenantCodes array = [
  'aabb'
  'bbcc'
  'ccdd'
]


// Create storage accounts
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = [for tenantCode in tenantCodes: {
  name: '${storagePrefix}${tenantCode}'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
  }
  // Assign the identity
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
        '${ManagedIdentityid}':{}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      identity: {
        // specify which identity to use
        userAssignedIdentity: ManagedIdentityid
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Keyvault'
      keyvaultproperties: {
        keyname: '${kvname}-${keyVaultKeyPrefix}${toUpper(tenantCode)}'
        keyvaulturi:uri
      }
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }

}]



resource storage_Accounts_name_default 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-04-01' = [ for (storageName, i) in tenantCodes :{
  parent: storageAccount[i]
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    changeFeed: {
      enabled: false
    }
    restorePolicy: {
      enabled: false
    }
    containerDeleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 7
    }
    cors: {
      corsRules: []
    }
    deleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 30
    }
    isVersioningEnabled: true
  }
}]

module connectionString 'shared.bicep' = [for (storageName, i) in tenantCodes :{
  scope: resourceGroup(keyvaultrg)
  name: storageName
  params: {
    storageAccountString: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount[i].name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount[i].id, storageAccount[i].apiVersion).keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}]
```

**keyvaultclient.bicep**

```
param deploymentIdOne string = newGuid()
param deploymentIdTwo string = newGuid()
output deploymentIdOne string = '${deploymentIdOne}-${deploymentIdTwo}'
output deploymentIdTwo string = deploymentIdTwo

param storagerg string = 'XXXX' //<=== Storage Accounts Resource Groups
param sharedManagedIdentity string = 'mgn-identity-shared'
param keyvaultmain string = 'XXXX' //<=== KeyVault Name where to create GUID AND Keys
param tenantCodes array = [
  'aabb'
  'bbcc'
  'ccdd'
]
var clientDataKeyPrefix = 'Key-Data-'

resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: sharedManagedIdentity
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

resource keyVaultClients 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: keyvaultmain
}
resource kvClientsKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2021-06-01-preview' = [for code in tenantCodes: {
  parent:keyVaultClients
  name: '${keyVaultClients.name}-${clientDataKeyPrefix}${toUpper(code)}'
  properties: {
    keySize: 2048
    kty: 'RSA'
    // Assign the least permission
    keyOps: [
      'unwrapKey'
      'wrapKey'
    ]
  }
}]
resource accessPolicy 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  parent:keyVaultClients
  name: 'add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
        permissions: {
          // minimum required permission
          keys: [
            'get'
            'unwrapKey'
            'wrapKey'
          ]
        } 
      }
    ]
  }
}
resource clientLearnersGuid 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-06-01-preview' = [for tenant in tenantCodes: {
  parent:keyVaultClients
  name: '${keyVaultClients.name}${tenant}'
  properties: {
    contentType: 'GUID Key'
    value: '${deploymentIdOne}-${deploymentIdTwo}'
  }
  dependsOn:kvClientsKey
}]
module StorageAccount 'storage.bicep' = [for (storageName, i) in tenantCodes :{
  scope: resourceGroup(storagerg)
  name: storageName
  params: {
    ManagedIdentityid:managedIdentity.id
    kvname:keyVaultClients.name
    uri:keyVaultClients.properties.vaultUri
  }
  dependsOn:clientLearnersGuid
}]
```

**shared.bicep**

```
param keyvaultshared string = 'XXXX' //<=== Key Vault Where to Store the Storage Connection String Secret
param storageAccountString string
param tenantCodes array = [
  'aabb'
  'bbcc'
  'ccdd'
]
resource keyVaultShared 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: keyvaultshared
}
resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-06-01-preview' = [for tenant in tenantCodes: {
  parent:keyVaultShared
  name: '${keyVaultShared.name}-test${tenant}'
  properties:{
    contentType: '${tenant} Storage Account Connection String'
    value: storageAccountString
  }
}]
```

Those script performs all the steps I needed based on the `tenantCode`. Which is just perfect. If I have only 1 `tenantCode` declared, everything goes smooth and perfect, but the issue I am facing raises when I try to declare more than 1. And this is the problem in details.

*When I declare more than 1 code, the script still created all the resources I needed: Storage accounts,Keys,Encryptions, GUID and ConnectionStrings Secrets. But it fails anyway on the `ConnectionStrings Secret`*.

The reason why it fails it because  in those files at this block of code:

**Shared.bicep**

```
resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-06-01-preview' = [for tenant in tenantCodes: {
  parent:keyVaultShared
  name: '${keyVaultShared.name}-test${tenant}'
  properties:{
    contentType: '${tenant} Storage Account Connection String'
    value: storageAccountString
  }
}]
```

and

*keuvaultsclient.bicep**

```
module StorageAccount 'storage.bicep' = [for (storageName, i) in tenantCodes :{
  scope: resourceGroup(storagerg)
  name: storageName
  params: {
    ManagedIdentityid:managedIdentity.id
    kvname:keyVaultClients.name
    uri:keyVaultClients.properties.vaultUri
  }
  dependsOn:clientLearnersGuid
}]
```

I have a multiple loop, on which I realised that in my shared keyvault under secrets, I have the correct amount of secrets (with 3 tenant codes I have 3 secrets) and under each secret I have 3 versions (for each tenant code it generate a new version for each secret). This looping error causes bicep script to `fail` with the following message:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"StorageAccountOperationInProgress\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access.\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          },\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"StorageAccountOperationInProgress\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access.\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

I am totally blocked at this stage and as I am a bicep beginner, I run out of all options and test to try to solve this issue.

**How to reproduce**

- Create 2 resource groups(one for the key vaults and one for the storage accounts)
- Update parameters with the correct kv names
- In all files add atleast 2 tenantCode on each file
- execute the command `az deployment group create -f ./keyvaultsclient.bicep -g <rg-where-keyvaults-are>`

I hope I explained clearly enough the issue I am facing and please if you need more details just let me know.

Thank you so much for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I tested the same code by doing some changes, Please try doing the same changes in the `.bicep` files :**

`keyvaultclient.bicep:`

Removed the loop for module as its creating 2 modules for the same thing.

```
module StorageAccount './storage.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup(storagerg)
  name: 'NestedStorage'
  params: {
    ManagedIdentityid:managedIdentity.id
    kvname:keyVaultClients.name
    uri:keyVaultClients.properties.vaultUri
  }
  dependsOn:clientLearnersGuid
}
```

`storage.bicep:`

Removed the loop for module and added the loop for only storage connection string which will store the outputs in array and pass it to the next module.

```
module connectionString './shared.bicep'={
  scope: resourceGroup(keyvaultrg)
  name: 'KeyvaultNested'
  params: {
    storageAccountString: [for (tenant,i) in tenantCodes :{
    id:'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount[i].name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount[i].id, storageAccount[i].apiVersion).keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }]
}
}
```

`shared.bicep:`

Changed the parameter type of `StorageAccountString` from string to array and added `[for (tenant,i) in tenantCodes` in the secret part so that I can give the value as `storageAccountString[i].id`  .

```
param storageAccountString array

resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-06-01-preview' = [for (tenant,i) in tenantCodes: {
  parent:keyVaultShared
  name: '${keyVaultShared.name}-test${tenant}'
  properties:{
    contentType: '${tenant} Storage Account Connection String'
    value: storageAccountString[i].id
  }
}]
```

**Outputs**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]